# mysql performance benchmark

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-web-services, profiling, amazon-rds

I'm thinking about moving our production env from a self hosted solution to amazon aws. I took a look at the different services and thought about using [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) as replacement for our mysql instances. The hardware we're using for our master seems to be better than the best hardware we can get when using rds (Quadruple Extra Large DB Instance). Since I can't simply move our production env to aws and see if the performance is still good enough I'd love to make some tests in advance.

I thought about creating a full query log from our current master, configure the rds instance and start to replay the full query log against it. Actually I don't even know if this kind of testing is a good idea but I guess you'll tell me if there are better ways to make sure the performance of mysql won't drop dramatically when making the move to rds.

1. Is there a preferred tool to replay the full query log?
2. at what metrics should I take a look while running the test

   - cpu usage?
   - memory usage?
   - disk usage?
   - query time?
   - anything else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend against replaying the query log - it's almost certainly not going to give you the information you want, and will take a significant amount of effort.

Firstly, you'd need to prepare your database so that replaying the query log won't break constraints when inserting, updating or deleting data, and that subsequent "select" queries will find the records they should find. This is distinctly non-trivial on anything other than a toy database - just taking a back-up and replaying the log doesn't necessarily guarantee the ordering of DML statements will match what happened on production. This may well give you a false sense of comfort - all your select statements return in a few milliseconds, because the data they're looking for doesn't exist!

Secondly, load and performance testing rarely works by replaying what happened on production - that doesn't (usually) reflect the peak conditions that will bring your system to its knees. For instance, most production systems run happily most of the time at <50% capacity, but go through spikes during the day, when they might reach 80% or more of capacity - that's what you care about, can your new environment handle the peaks.

My recommendation would be to use a tool like [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to write performance scripts (either directly to the database using the JDBC driver, or through the front end if you've got a web appilcation). Your performance scripts should reflect the behaviour you see from users, and be parameterized so they're not dependent on the order in which records are created.

Set yourself some performance targets (ideally based on current production levels, with a multiplier to cover you against spikes), e.g. "100 concurrent users, with no query taking more than 1 second"), and use JMeter to simulate that load. If you reach it first time, congratulations - go home! If not, look at the performance counters to see where the bottleneck is; see if you can alleviate that bottleneck (or tune your queries, your awesome on-premise hardware may be hiding some performance issues). Typical bottlenecks are CPU, RAM, and disk I/O.

Experiment with different test scenarios - "lots of writes", "lots of reads", "lots of reporting queries", and mix them up.

The idea is to understand the bottlenecks on the system, and see how far you are from those bottleneck, and understand what you can do to alleviate them. Once you know that, your decision to migrate will be far more robust.

Comment: I've accepted your answer since your given response would be the best way to go. Sadly it's not easy to create valid test suites if your application has hundreds of use cases. I just found http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/07/10/percona-playback-0-3-development-release/ which seems to be perfect for situations like this.